# Checking a column of a matrix for numbers greater than 4 in r

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I am trying to create an if statement with the condition "if any numbers in the column [,1] of Matrix B are greater than 4 do this......"

I am unsure of how to check the whole column.

So far I have managed to find out whether it is true or false by doing this:

```
B[,1] > 4
```

and it comes back with:

```
FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I want to make it so if at least one statement came back as "TRUE" it would carry out the 'if' statement:

```
if ((B[,1] > 4) == TRUE){
  Move <- append(Move, 5)
}
```

This comes up with the Warning message:

```
In if ((B[, 1] > 4) == TRUE) Move :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How should I code it to check all the values in the column? I hope I have made my problem clear and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `any(B[, 1] > 4)`

Answer (score 2):

use `any`

```
if (any(B[,1] > 4) ){
  Move <- append(Move, 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(B, 2, function(x) x > 4)[,1]
```

and the if condition would be

```
if(mean(apply(B, 2, function(x) x > 4)[,1]) >0){}
```

because TRUE evaluates to 1 and FALSE to 0

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is "Move", but if you just want another vector depending on a condition, use the `ifelse` function:

```r
x <- sample(1:20)     # create example data
ifelse(x > 4, 5, x)
```